# Protractor Expected Condition Wrapper to return a boolean promise

Tags: protractor

I am trying to wrap an expected condition in a base class to enable as much dry code as possible however I am having an issue with the promise being returned. I have looked quite a bit for a solution but have yet found none which satisfy my needs.

## Base Class (POM)

```
import { browser, by, element, ElementArrayFinder, ElementFinder, Locator, ExpectedConditions, protractor } from 'protractor';

export class BasePage {
    //#region Page Properties
    ...
    //#endregion Page Properties

    //#region Contructor
    ...
    //#endregion Contructor

    //#region Getters
    ...
    //#endregion Getters

    //#region Page Methods
    ...

public async waitUntilElementPresent(item: ElementFinder, timeToWait: number = 5000): Promise<Boolean> {
    const until = ExpectedConditions;
    return browser.wait(until.presenceOf(item), timeToWait, `Element ${item.locator} is taking too long to become present in the DOM. Waiting Time : ${timeToWait}`).then(() => {
        return true;
    }, () => {
        return false;
    });
}

public async waitUntilElementClickable(item: ElementFinder, timeToWait: number = 5000): Promise<Boolean> {
    const until = ExpectedConditions;
    return browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(item), timeToWait, `Element ${item.locator} is taking too long to become clickable. Waiting Time : ${timeToWait}`).then(() => {
        return true;
    }, () => {
        return false;
    });
}

public async waitUntilElementVisible(item: ElementFinder, timeToWait: number = 5000): Promise<Boolean> {
    const until = ExpectedConditions;
    return browser.wait(until.visibilityOf(item), timeToWait, `Element ${item.locator} is taking too long to become visible. Waiting Time : ${timeToWait}`).then(() => {
        return true;
    }, () => {
        return false;
    });
}
//#endregion Page Methods
}
```

## MyPage Class (POM)

```
import { by, element, ElementFinder, Locator } from 'protractor';
import { BasePage } from '../../common/basePageObjects/basePage';

export class MyPage extends BasePage {

    //#region Page Properties
    private closeButton: Locator;
    //#endregion Page Properties

    //#region Contructor
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.closeButton = by.css('closeBtn');
    }
    //#endregion Contructor

    //#region Getters
    public get CloseButton(): ElementFinder {
        return element(this.closeButton);
    }
    //#endregion Getters

    //#region Page Methods
    public async clickOnCloseButton() {
        await this.CloseButton.click();
    }
    //#endregion Page Methods
}
```

## Step

```
const myPage: MyPage = new MyPage(); // Extends base class

Then(/^I close my Page popup$/, async () => {
    await expect(myPage.waitUntilElementVisible(myPage.CloseButton, 5000)).to.be.true;
});
```

When I debug the code I come across an Assertion Error : "expected {} to be true". Now this does make sense I guess since browser.wait returns promise.Promise<{}>. I have tried different approaches but would prefer an approach that lets me wait for a stipulated amount of time and if the element does meet the EC, return true, if not return false, or in this case a boolean promise.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
expect(await myPage.waitUntilElementVisible ...
```

There were changes since Protractor 5.2.1:

Before

```
await expect(getPromise()).toEqual(42);
```

After

```
expect(await getPromise()).toEqual(42);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see you use `async`. Could you try the same but with `await`:

```
public async waitUntilElementClickable(item: ElementFinder, timeToWait: number = 5000): Promise<Boolean> {
    const until = ExpectedConditions;
    await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(item), timeToWait, `Element ${item.locator} is taking too long to become clickable. Waiting Time : ${timeToWait}`);
    return true;
}
```